# C++ Store Edit Box Value Into A Int

Tags: c++, windows

I need to Read the value that is typed into a EditBox and save into into a Int.
Does anyone know how to do this?? this is the code i have so far..

```
        case EditAge: {
       if (HIWORD(wParam) == EN_CHANGE)
```

Comment: It would be helpful to post a little more information along with the question -- you're allowed to edit your original post -- and indicate whether this is an MFC or Windows SDK kind of GUI application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, that's a start, but did you even try to retrieve the text? Or do you have issues converting the text to a number? For future questions, try to be more specific. You're most likely looking for something like this line (don't forget to check to see if you're in the right text box!):

```
GetDlgItemText(dialoghandle, LOWORD(wParam) /* the control id */, text /* pointer where the text should go */, 256 /* max number of elements */);
```

Once you've got the text, you can use e.g. `strtol()` to parse the string and retrieve a number.

Edit:
You could actually use `GetDlgItemInt()`, documented [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645485(v=vs.85).aspx), to retrieve an integer right away.